# Find the derivative of $\int_{0}^{\ln(x)} \sqrt{t^5+1}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the derivative of the definite integral from $0$ to $\ln(x)$ of $\sqrt{t^5+1}\,dt.$

I'm not sure how to take the derivative of a definite integral.

Comment: How do you take the derivative in general?

Comment: Do you want to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ ?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: Hint: if it were just $x$ instead of $\ln(x)$ in the upper limit, how would you do it? This situation is very similar except that there is an additional chain rule step.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(t)$ be a primitive of $\sqrt{t^5+1}$.

Then, by the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{\ln x}\sqrt{t^5+1}\,dt = \frac{d}{dx}\left(F(\ln x)-F(0)\right) = \frac{1}{x}\,F'(\ln x) = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{1+\ln^5 x}}{x}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) and [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to get
$$f(x)=\int_0^{\ln x} g(t)dt,\quad g(t)=\sqrt{t^5+1}$$
$$f(x)=G(\ln x)-G(0)$$
$$f'(x)=G'(\ln x)\cdot\frac1x=\frac{\sqrt{\ln(x)^5+1}}{x}$$

where $g(x)=G'(x)$.